# Filtering rows from dataframe based on the values of the previous rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
    A
1   1000
2   1000
3   1001
4   1001
5   10
6   1000
7   1010
8   9
9   10
10  6
11  999
12  10110
13  10111
14  1000
```

I am trying to clean my dataframe in the following way:
For every row having more value than 1.5 times the previous row value or less than 0.5 times the previous row value, drop it.
But If the previous row is a to-drop row, comparison must be made with the immediate previous NON-to-drop row. (For example Index 9, 10 or 13 in my dataframe) 
So the final dataframe should be like:

```
    A
1   1000
2   1000
3   1001
4   1001
6   1000
7   1010
11  999
14  1000
```

My dataframe is really huge so performance is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far to solve the problem?

Comment: pct_change.between(-0.5,0.5)?

Comment: @ansev this sort of thing needs a for loop as in piRSquared's answer.

Comment: yes, it is true that you need for loop but I think we could use pct-change in a more elegant solution

Comment: I'm wondering whether one could iteratively generate a mask using vectorized operations... performance would depend on specific distribution of dropped rows, supposedly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You can't get away from looping through each row

Tips

- Avoid creating new (expensive to create) objects for each row
- Use a memory efficient iteration

---

#### I'd use a generator

I'll pass a series to a function and yield the index values for which rows satisfy the conditions.

```
def f(s):
    it = s.iteritems()
    i, v = next(it)
    yield i                          # Yield the first one
    for j, x in it:
        if .5 * v <= x <= 1.5 * v:
            yield j                  # Yield the ones that satisfy
            v = x                    # Update the comparative value

df.loc[list(f(df.A))]                # Use `loc` with index values
                                     # yielded by my generator

       A
1   1000
2   1000
3   1001
4   1001
6   1000
7   1010
11   999
14  1000
```

Comment: should by `.5 * v <= x <= 1.5 * v`

Answer (score 1):

One alternative could be to use [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to *push forward* the last valid value and then filter out the values that are different from the original, e.g:

```
from itertools import accumulate


def change(x, y, pct=0.5):
    if pct * x <= y <= (1 + pct) * x:
        return y
    return x

# create a mask filtering out the values that are different from the original A
mask = (df.A == list(accumulate(df.A, change)))

print(df[mask])
```

**Output**

```
       A
1   1000
2   1000
3   1001
4   1001
6   1000
7   1010
11   999
14  1000
```

Just to get an idea, see how the *accumulated* column (change) compares to the original side-by-side:

```
        A  change
1    1000    1000
2    1000    1000
3    1001    1001
4    1001    1001
5      10    1001
6    1000    1000
7    1010    1010
8       9    1010
9      10    1010
10      6    1010
11    999     999
12  10110     999
13  10111     999
14   1000    1000
```

**Update**

To make it in the function call do:

```
mask = (df.A == list(accumulate(df.A, lambda x, y : change(x, y, pct=0.5))))
```

Comment: Great!. How could I pass the 0.5 as parameter?

Comment: @Alfonso_MA You mean a parameter to the function?

Comment: Yeah, a parameter to change function

Comment: But i meant in the function call

Comment: @Alfonso_MA see now